# Grouping related records in many to many table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, many-to-many

I Have a table 'C' in MySQL db with the following structure:

*Object1Id (int)* - **PK** and has one to many relation to table 'A',

*Object2Id (int)* - **PK** and has one to many relation to table 'A',

*OccuranceId (int)* - **FK** and has one to many relation to table 'B'.

Basically table 'C' has many to many relation with table 'A' and one to many relation with table 'B'.

The data:

```
1, 3, 1
1, 3, 39
3, 1, 402
3, 1, 27
1, 3, 40
3, 1, 12
```

I try to group the records with the query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN least(Object1Id, Object2Id) = Object1Id THEN Object1Id ELSE Object2Id END AS Object1Id, 
       CASE WHEN Greatest(Object1Id, Object2Id) = Object2Id THEN Object2Id ELSE Object1Id END AS Object2Id, 
       count(OccuranceId) AS OccuranceCount
FROM 'C'
GROUP BY Object1Id, Object2Id
```

The result I get back from the query are:

1, 3, 3 - for object1Id = 1 and Object2Id = 3

1, 3, 3 - for Object1Id = 3 and Object2Id = 1

I would like the result to sum up as : 1, 3, 6

How can I produce the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: can u format your code pls, no one can read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would simplify the query to

```
SELECT least(Object1Id, Object2Id) AS Object1Id,
       Greatest(Object1Id, Object2Id) AS Object2Id,
       count(OccuranceId) AS OccuranceCount
FROM C
GROUP BY Object1Id, Object2Id
```

Your query doesn't work, because you have columns `object1id` and `object2id` and reuse these names for the result columns `least()` and `greatest()`. But the `group by` clause groups by the table columns not your result columns. When you rename the result columns to some other names, it works as you expect

```
SELECT least(Object1Id, Object2Id) AS least_val,
       Greatest(Object1Id, Object2Id) AS greatest_val,
       count(OccuranceId) AS OccuranceCount
FROM C
GROUP BY least_val, greatest_val
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9e32/7/0) for testing

Answer (score 0):

yes!

```
SELECT Object1Id, Object2Id, sum(OccuranceCount)
FROM (

__ YOUR SELECT __

) foo
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to make this answer useful - thanks.

Comment: This could work too. but I'll go with Olaf's answer. Thanks for helping.